# Adding JScrollPane to JSplitPane

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane, jsplitpane

Come to a bit of a mind block here: I need to turn the image into a JScrollPane. Should be easy but I'm a bit lost.

```
JSplitPane pane1;

pane1 = new JSplitPane(JSplitPane.HORIZONTAL_SPLIT, 
    new JLabel("hi"), 
    (new JLabel(new ImageIcon(image))));
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could do:

```
pane1 = new JSplitPane(JSplitPane.HORIZONTAL_SPLIT, new JLabel("hi"),
             (new JScrollPane(new JLabel(new ImageIcon(image)))));
```